# display: table-cell causing firefox and opera to ignore max-width and max-height properties

Tags: css, firefox, opera, vertical-alignment, css-tables

If you would please go to http://debourg-dev.ch/syselcloud/erp-rh/ you will see that in firefox and opera the images are not using the max-height property. This is because I'm using display:table-cell to vertically align them, if I remove display: table-cell it works fine. How can I vertically align these images with display: table-cell and get firefox and opera to make use of the correct max-height value?

The concerned code is:

```
.partenaire-logo-wrap {
height: 110px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}

.partenaire-logo-wrap img {
max-height: 90px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing the images be 90px high in Firefox on the link above...  What exactly is not using max-height?

Answer (score 0):

```
.partenaire-logo-wrap img {
max-height: 90px;
-moz-height:90px;
-o-height:90px;
}
```

I am getting this information from here if you want to check out this post

[Max-height ignored in Firefox, works in Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925879/max-height-ignored-in-firefox-works-in-chrome-and-safari)