# Why do Firefox and Chrome display this image differently?

Tags: html, css

My image appears to display differently in chrome and firefox.

Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/4FGad/2/ open it in firefox and chrome and you will see the image dimensions are different.

Chrome displays the image as I want.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="imageContent">
        <div id="bigImgCon">    
<a href="<?php echo $firstImg; ?>" rel="lightbox"><img id="firstImage" rel="lightbox" src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" /></a>

        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#imageContent {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div#bigImgCon {
    width:100%;
    max-height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:red;
}
img#firstImage {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: It would be great with some screenshots of the differences.

Comment: @Vallentin Click on the jsfiddle link provided, open it in Chrome then Firefox.

Comment: @Matt A good, self-contained SO question would include screenshots.

Comment: @admdrew That makes sense, but I see links to jsfiddle on many CSS-related posts (with no screen shots)

Comment: @Matt Oh totally agreed. I just also know the pain of having to check something in multiple browsers.

Comment: @Matt some don't have multiple browsers installed. Also yes other CSS related posts don't have screenshots either and use jsFiddle, but all other posts aren't about differences in various browsers.

Comment: @Vallentin I recently moved to linux and I don't currently have an application that easily screenshots a section of a page without doing print screen and opening up gimp. Call it lazy but this was pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Vallentin Help or don't help, but to me it's annoying when "experts" complain about a question where someone made an effort to provide a lot of detail.  Maybe it's just me and that doesn't bother anyone else on here.

Comment: @Matt I agree, I don't mind someone suggesting I provide a screenshot and admdrew has a point about self contained questions. To just come in though and not contribute anything to the actual question is a little annoying. Especially if there is already enough information on the page to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox, I changed max-height to height and it works the same as Chrome... the first one that sets height to 300px is the one that did the trick.

Update... Take the max-height off of div#bgImgCon and put it on the div#imageContent class instead. It appears to me like that will do the trick for you.

```
div#bigImgCon {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:10px;
    background-color:red;
}
img#firstImage {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:300px;
    cursor:hand;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the 'max-height' for images that are smaller than 300px.

Comment: You can still have max-height, but if you want it to display the actual height of the image (same as in chrome), you'll have to include the height attribute.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp max-height OVERRIDES height.

Comment: I found this thread on here that looks like it would work as well for you.  Just try to set body height in your CSS:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925879/max-height-ignored-in-firefox-works-in-chrome-and-safari

Comment: Thanks, I'll have look :)

Comment: I still don't quite understand how to make my element have a dynamic height, I'm already using `html, body{height:100%; width:100%;}`

Comment: F12 to open developer tools in Firefox, the issue is with the outer container (red image).  Again when I check/uncheck max-height in the DOM Inspector for the div#bigImgCon css class, it changes things.  I'm continuing to experiment with the CSS in there...if I figure out the dynamic nature of it, I'll let you know.  One thing to verify is which browser is actually correct.  It looks like Firefox is honoring max-height, Chrome is not.

Comment: @UzmakiDev Take the max-height off of div#bgImgCon and put it on the div#imageContent class instead.  It appears to me like that will do the trick for you.

Comment: Yea, you're right, I removed max-height from bigImgCon and put it on first image and it worked great. Thank you. Edit your question and I'll tick you :)

Comment: Ha, just noticed you did. Thanks.

Comment: The reason for that is the inner div is inheriting the height/width of the outer div.  So to make it "dynamic" you need to control the outer-most container, and not as much on the inner one.  I hope that makes sense.