# Max-height fluid image responsive doesn't work in Chrome, Firefox etc. but works in Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to accomplish image resizing for height (I'm aware of width:100%, height:auto for width resizing). The below setup works in Safari (~8.02) but Chrome and Firefox (latest) don't care at all. Any ideas? If no CSS hacks exist, I'm open to jQuery solutions (I guess).

```css
body, html {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.full {
  width:100%;
  
}

.block {
  background: lightcoral;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/709x534" class="logo">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the CSS above, declaring a height of 100% on the container (in this case, .block) resolved the issue on Chrome and Firefox. It now matches Safari behavior as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to purposely distort your image after it goes beyond an 80% height?
Check out this post... [Max-height ignored in Firefox, works in Chrome and Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925879/max-height-ignored-in-firefox-works-in-chrome-and-safari)

Comment: The solution works fine in Safari but not Chrome (let alone Firefox). The image doesn't appear to be distorted and the link provided is using less than 100% width. If you view in Safari, you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the CSS above, declaring a height of 100% on the container (in this case, .block) resolved the issue on Chrome and Firefox. It now matches Safari behavior as intended:

```css
body, html {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

body {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.full {
  width:100%;
  
}

.block {
  background: lightcoral;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}

.logo {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="block">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/709x534" class="logo">
  </div>
</div>
```