# Min-width of 100% does not work in Firefox, but works in Chrome

Tags: css, firefox, responsive-design, width

I'm trying to set the width on a responsive image so it scales according to window size.
It works in Chrome but not in Firefox, and now causes images to be misaligned. I've tried setting `html` and `body` elements to 100% as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925879/max-height-ignored-in-firefox-works-in-chrome-and-safari).

Check [this link](https://www.toptrouwen.nl/trouwshop) to see it live.

And here's the code in question (but check it live to be sure as it depends on the actual image sizes whether the UI breaks in FireFox):

**HTML**

```
<div style="height: 300px;" class="product1">
    <div class="prodtitle">
        <span itemprop="name"><a title="Paxton And Percival Pig Pair" href="/weddingshop/party-supplies/52-11191697/paxton-and-percival-pig-pair">Paxton And Percival Pig Pair</a></span>
    </div>
    <div class="description">

        <center>
        <div class="image">
            <a href="/weddingshop/party-supplies/52-11191697/paxton-and-percival-pig-pair" title="Paxton And Percival Pig Pair"><img src="http://www.shindigz.com/images/itm_img/8F022D.jpg" alt="Paxton And Percival Pig Pair"></a>
        </div>
        </center>

        <span itemprop="description">These 3D Pigs are made of cardboard and are freestanding.&nbsp; Bandan...</span>
            <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
                <div class="price">
                    <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD"></span><span itemprop="price" content="44.99">44.99</span>  
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>        


</div>
```

**style**

```
product1 {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset;
    position: relative;
}

.product1 .image a img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 178px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a piece of example code that demonstrates the issue? Preferable as a snippet here in the question.

Comment: Anyway, your webpage has a lot of errors (223 according to the W3 validator; 161 according to my own parser which ignores the faulty DOCTYPE definition), so maybe it's just a matter of the different browsers using different methods of error correction.

Comment: @MrLister: Thanks, I was unaware of those errors. But what is wrong with my DOCTYPE definition?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the DOCTYPE _declaration_, not definition. My bad. This is the one for a XHTML 1.0 file, while the file type and contents are HTML5.

Comment: @MrLister: ah, thanks! I fixed that, but still Firefox is showing the page styled ugly....what else can it be?